# VBA refer to chart name

Tags: vba

Why this does not work:

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Sale").Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 1000
```

while this does:

```
  With ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary)
    .MinimumScale = 1000
  End With
```

First I did this:

```
ActiveChart.Parent.Name="Sale"
```

I was not able to do this:

```
ActiveChart.Name="Sale"
```

I want to refer specifically to the chart "Sale", not to ActiveChart.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A ChartObject is just a "container" for a Chart on a worksheet: you need to access its `Chart` property to get to the chart itself:

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Sale").Chart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 1000
```

Answer (score -2):

You can set the name of the chart to which you intend to refer using the following:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).name = "Sale"
```

Note that the value of `1` in `Shapes(1)` is the Chart number of the first chart you create.

If you are creating more than one (1) chart, you will need to update the number accordingly.

I hope this helps you.

Thank you.

Peace.

Comment: OP asked how to *refer* to a chart by it's name (not how to *set* the name).